# What is the difference between linux-oem-22.04 and linux-oem-22.04a packages?

Tags: 22.04, oem

I want to use kernel 5.17 on my desktop PC and I found that linux-oem-22.04 and linux-oem-22.04a packages provide kernel 5.17. So I want to know the difference between them to select a proper package?

Comment: Did you find a precise answer for this?

Comment: No, but I've installed linux-oem-22.04 package and I get updates of Linux kernel 5.17.

Answer (score 3):

I think that linux-oem-22.04 will update your kernel to whatever kernel they will release as OEM at later date. Something like meta-package which will currently install kernel 5.17, but later when they release another OEM kernel, like 5.18 or 5.19, system will offer upgrade. But when you install "a" kernel, you will stay on it forever, even if they release a "b" OEM kernel etc.

Comment: "I think that linux-oem-22.04 will update your kernel to whatever kernel they will release as OEM at later date." 

Unfortunately not: `linux-oem-22.04` still points to `linux-oem-22.04a`, despite `linux-oem-22.04b` and `linux-oem-22.04c` being available.

Answer (score 0):

22.04a was released after 22.04 so 22.04a is the more recent version. There shouldn't be any real difference there so there is nothing to worry about, the 'a' version might just be a bug fix or something.